# Conditional count

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 500 numbers stored in column A.

Which formula should I use to count the number of those that satisfy the condition `6<X<8`? (I'm new to Excel so please give me instructions in detail.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `COUNTIF` function.

Enter the ff. formula into an empty cell, and it should give you how many `6`'s there are in column A.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A500, 6)
```

If you want to count the number of values greater than or equal to 6:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A500, ">=6")
```

If you want to count the number of values greater than 6 and less than 8 (6 < x < 8):

<sub>**(MS Excel 2007 and above)**</sub>

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A500, ">6", A1:A500, "<8")
```

<sub>**(MS Excel 2003)**</sub>

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A500, "<8")-COUNTIF(A1:A500, ">6")
```

Comment: how do I do 6<X<8?

Answer (score 0):

Create another column (say, B) and apply a formula `=IF(A1>6 AND A1<8, 1,0)`

Then do a sum on that column

This is even easier if you use the "format as table" option

Select your table, and use the "Format as Table" option

Then, enter the condition as shown in the screenshot

http://snag.gy/ENDky.jpg

[image]

Finally add a sum on that column

(sorry, but I dont know  how to do an AND in excel :) )

Comment: it must be a bug of this site! I wrote 6<X<8 but it just displays X. You can check it in the edit.

Comment: and why A1? since the values are in A1-A500

Comment: @Chin Just used A1 as an example. Wait, will put a more detailed example